# Ancestors rebuild from parent id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ancestor

I have category model that has a tree structure. In my database I have about 1500 records.
When I try rebuild ancestry from parent id with command "Category.build_ancestry_from_parent_ids!" I get nil as a result.

Here are results.

1.9.2p290 :006 > Category.build_ancestry_from_parent_ids!
  Category Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."parent_id" IS NULL AND ("categories"."id" >= 0) ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1000
 => nil

I'm following directions from https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry , but seems like I am missing something.

Is any one had same issue before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to put parameters to make this work properly.

```
Category.build_ancestry_from_parent_ids!(parent_id =0 , ancestry =0)
```

It's possible to put `parent_id =1`, then transition will skip all categories that belong to the root level.